# How can I programatically (C#) read the autoscale settings for a WebApp?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to build a small program to change the autoscale settings for our Azure WebApps, using the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites NuGet packages.

I have been roughly following the guide [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2014/02/20/how-to-use-windows-azure-monitoring-services-management-library-to-create-an-autoscale-rule/).

However, we are interested in scaling WebApps / App Services rather than Cloud Services, so I am trying to use the same code to read the autoscale settings but providing a resource ID for our WebApp. I have already got the credentials required for making a connection (using a browser window popup for Active Directory authentication, but I understand we can use X.509 management certificates for non-interactive programs).

This is the request I'm trying to make. Credentials already established, and an exception is thrown earlier if they're not valid.

```
AutoscaleClient autoscaleClient = new AutoscaleClient(credentials);
var resourceId = AutoscaleResourceIdBuilder.BuildWebSiteResourceId(webspaceName: WebSpaceNames.NorthEuropeWebSpace, serverFarmName: "Default2");
AutoscaleSettingGetResponse get = autoscaleClient.Settings.Get(resourceId); // exception here
```

The WebApp (let's call it "MyWebApp") is part of an App Service Plan called "Default2" (Standard: 1 small), in a Resource Group called "WebDevResources", in the North Europe region. I expect that my problem is that I am using the wrong names to build the resourceId in the code - the naming conventions in the library don't map well onto what I can see in the Azure Portal.

I'm assuming that BuildWebSiteResourceId is the correct method to call, see MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.monitoring.utilities.autoscaleresourceidbuilder.aspx).

However the two parameters it takes are webspaceName and serverFarmName, neither of which match anything in the Azure portal (or Google). I found another example which seemed to be using the WebApp's geo region for webSpaceName, so I've used the predefined value for North Europe where our app is hosted.

While trying to find the correct value for serverFarmName in the Azure Portal, I found the Resource ID for the App Service Plan, which looks like this:

`/subscriptions/{subscription-guid}/resourceGroups/WebDevResources/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/Default2`

That resource ID isn't valid for the call I'm trying to make, but it does support the idea that a 'serverfarm' is the same as an App Service Plan.

When I run the code, regardless of whether the resourceId parameters seem to be correct or garbage, I get this error response:

`<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    {"Code":"SettingNotFound","Message":"Could not find the autoscale settings."}
</string>`

So, how can I construct the correct resource ID for my WebApp or App Service Plan? Or alternatively, is there a different tree I should be barking up to programatially manage WebApp scaling?

*Update:*
The solution below got the info I wanted. I also found the Azure resource explorer at resources.azure.com extremely useful to browse existing resources and find the correct names. For example, the name for my autoscale settings is actually "Default2-WebDevResources", i.e. "{AppServicePlan}-{ResourceGroup}" which I wouldn't have expected.

Comment: Is your App Service Plan pricing tier Standard & above?

Comment: The pricing tier is listed as Standard: 1 small, which I understand to be the S1 pricing tier. I've also created an autoscaling plan through the Azure Portal, which allowed me to specify up to 10 instances.

Comment: Thanks for the update to your original question, which provide some very useful tips to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide which you're following is based on the Azure Service Management model, aka Classic mode, which is deprecated and only exists mainly for backward compatibility support.

You should use the latest
[Microsoft.Azure.Insights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Insights/0.14.1-preview) nuget package for getting the **autoscale** settings.

Sample code using the nuget above is as below:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights;
using Microsoft.Rest;

//... Get necessary values for the required parameters 

var client = new InsightsManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(token));
client.AutoscaleSettings.Get(resourceGroupName, autoScaleSettingName);
```

Besides, the **autoscalesettings** is a resource under the "**Microsoft.Insights**" provider and not under the "**Microsoft.Web**" provider, which explains why you are not able to find it with your serverfarm resourceId.

See the [REST API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931944.aspx) below for getting the autoscale settings.

```
GET
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/microsoft.insights/autoscaleSettings/{autoscale-setting-name}?api-version={api-version}
```

Comment: Thank you, that does what I was hoping for.

Comment: For completeness I should note that I also had to set the SubscriptionID on the client object, but that was easy to figure out from the sample code you provided.

Comment: var client = new InsightsManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(authToken));
            client.SubscriptionId = Settings.SubscriptionId;
            var settings = client.AutoscaleSettings.Get(Settings.ResourceGroupName, Settings.AutoScaleSettingName);

Comment: Yes, that is what my comment has noted you need to populate the necessary parameters

Answer (score 3):

There is a preview service https://resources.azure.com/ where you can inspect all your resources easily. If you search for `autoscale` in the UI you will easily find the settings for your resource. It will also show you how to call the relevant REST Api endpoint to read or update that resorce.

[image: Azure Resource Explorer]

It's a great tool for revealing a lot of details for your deployed resources and it will actually give you an ARM template stub for the resource you are looking at.

And to answer your question, you could programmatically call the REST API from a client with updated settings for autoscale. The REST API is one way of doing this, the SDK another and PowerShell a third.